# Elasticseach Multisearch only returns 1 set of results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to return multiple "buckets" of results from Elasticsearch in one HTTP request.

I'm using the [_msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) API.

I'm using the following query:

```
POST /_msearch

{"index" : "[INDEXNAME]", "type":"post"}
{"query" : {"match" : {"post_type":"team-member"}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
{"index" : "[INDEXNAME]", "type": "post"}
{"query" : {"match" : {"post_type": "article"}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
```

The query executes without error, but the results only return one object, where it seems it shoul be two (one for the 10 team-members, and one for the 10 articles):

```
    {
        "responses": [
            {
                "took": 1,
                "timed_out": false,
                "_shards": {
                    "total": 4,
                    "successful": 4,
                    "failed": 0
                },
                "hits": {
                    "total": 191,
                    "max_score": 3.825032,
                    "hits": [
                       {...}
                    ]
                }
            }, // second query should be here, no?
        ]
    }
```

Is my query construction wrong, or am I misunderstanding how this should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of a `_msearch` request **must follow** the [bulk API format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). It must look something like this:

```
header\n
body\n
header\n
body\n
```

The header part includes which index / indices to search on, optional (mapping) types to search on, the `search_type`, `preference`, and `routing`. The body includes the typical search body request (including the `query`, `aggregations`, `from`, `size`, and so on).

**NOTE:** the final line of data must end with a newline character `\n`.

Make sure your query follows this format (from your code example, depending on the environment, as you've added two new lines after `POST /_msearch`, your query may or may not work; you should only add one new line) . If the `responses` array only has one result, then, in your case, the last query is somehow discarded - again, check its format.

Comment: "NOTE: the final line of data must end with a newline character \n." did the trick--thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem actually, but you should check "Bulk API", it's similar.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: Sure, but it seems that's only for indexing/deleting and not for querying.

Comment: I don't see anything bad in your request. Sometimes ou can't do a "multi search request" because your mapping don't offer your this possibility. I suggest you to take an other alternative with the aggregations.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about mapping. Can you point to any resources that might outline how to set up my mappings to allow for multisearch?